# OpenSSL connection to an imap server over explicit port works, but fails on implicit port

Tags: email, imap, openssl, ruby-on-rails, mail-server

I have a mail server to which I'm connecting from a ruby application using protocol IMAP.
But I get an error in rails console:

```
Loading dev environment (Rails 7.0.4)
irb(main):001:0> @connection = Net::IMAP.new('mail.test.com.test', 993, true)

Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):1
        1: from (irb):1:in `new'
Errno::ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect)
```

Vesrions used:

```
rails: 7.0.4 
ruby: ruby 2.7.3p183
```

**Note:**

We have firewall in between, and rule for port 993 is allowed.

```
nc -vz mail.test.com.test 993

mail.test.com.test (192.168.1.186:993) open
```

So I started testing with OpenSSL over implicit port `993` and recieved error:

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.test.com.test:993 


CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 319 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

But it seems that the IMAP connection over an explicit port `143` with TLS works fine:

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.test.com.test:143 -starttls imap -brief


CONNECTION ESTABLISHED
Protocol version: TLSv1.2
Ciphersuite: <suite>
Peer certificate: CN = mail.test.com.test
Hash used: SHA256
Signature type: RSA
Verification: OK
Server Temp Key: <key>, P-384, 384 bits
. OK CAPABILITY completed.
```

In the rails console, it would be like this:

```
irb(main):061:0> @connection = Net::IMAP.new('mail.test.com.test', 143, false)
    
=> #<Net::IMAP:0x0000f0 @mon_data=#<Monitor:0x0000d78>, @mon_data_owner_object_id=5230, @host="mail.test.com.test", @port=143, @tag_prefix="RUBY", @tagno=0, @open_timeout=30, @idl...  
    
      
irb(main):064:0> @connection.starttls
        
=> #<struct Net::IMAP::TaggedResponse tag="RUBY0001", name="OK", data=#<struct Net::IMAP::ResponseText code=nil, text="Begin TLS negotiation now.">, raw_data="RUBY0001 OK Begin TLS negotiation now.\r\n">
```

Why does this happen? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What does the server say about it?

Comment: @user1686 you mean, the logs from mail server?

Comment: Yes; it's the mail server that's not sending you the right handshake, so you need to check from the server's side why that is the case.